# Implementing SVM RFE and cannot locate library

Tags: r, svm, rfe

I'm looking to set up SVM RFE and found the SO article here: [Implementation of SVM-RFE Algorithm in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891965/implementation-of-svm-rfe-algorithm-in-r/52141997#52141997)

It appears that the SVM function in the code is different from that in the e1071 library and i've been looking around to find the library with the function referenced in the above article, with no luck.  The parameters in the example linked above appear different from what's used the e1071 library and i'm hoping someone out there might have some insight.  I've been looking around a lot without any luck in tracking down the difference between "SVM()" in the example and "svm()" from e1071.

Comment: There is no need to implement this manually, the `caret` package has `rfe` which can be used with pretty much any method available.

Comment: Thank you missuse!

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933704/feature-selection-with-caret-rfe-and-training-with-another-method/51934572#51934572) is an answer to get you going.